# JQuery script rendering using bundles in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bundletransformer

I am trying to render jquery using bundles.

I added jquery in `BundleConfig.vb` as

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
                    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                             "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"))
```

And I added

```
<%=Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")%>
```

in aspx file.

When I look at the source code of the file I get something like

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.1.js" style=""></script>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

I am able to render all other scripts and styles without any problems.

Other script bundles in `BundleConfig.vb`

```
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqtree").Include(
               "~/Scripts/tree.jquery.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.cookie.js",
                "~/Scripts/jqtreeinit.js"
               ))
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/knockout").Include(
                "~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"
                ))
    bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/searchKey").Include(
                "~/Scripts/ViewModels/assetViewModel.js",
                "~/Scripts/AjaxTextBoxSuggestions.js"
                ))
```

Do you have any idea about style attribute added to the script tag and style tag between jquery and jqueryUI?

Comment: Very weird... not only the `style` between the 2 scripts, but the `style=""` attribute inside the first `script` reference.

Comment: I agree, very weird. Did you try using `Bundle()` and giving it a new instance of `JsTransformer`? Wonder what happens if you disable `debug` mode. Did you try?

Comment: Are you certain that you haven't accidentally confused a `Style` for a `Script` anywhere in the bundles code?

Comment: @Klors If I use Styles.Render I may get `style` tag instead of `script` tag

Comment: @ram2013 ignore me, I've just tried it and they just come out as normal `<link>` elements

Comment: You say "aspx file", so I guess it's a WebForms App? You say the other bundles render without problems. Could you please show the rest of your `BundleConfig.vb` and the render tags in the aspx.

Comment: @LinusCaldwell I added other bundles in `BundleConfig.vb` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know why you see this strange behavior, but I'd guess the following could be a solution, even if it is a little hacky. If it's ok for you, you may use `Scripts.Url()`:

```html
<script src="<%=Scripts.Url("~/bundles/jquery")%>"></script>
```

The drawback of course is that all files in the bundle get combined even without debug mode, but with activated debugging

```xml
<!-- web.config -->
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

they should not get compressed, so JavaScript debugging should be possible if you want to.

Comment: Even above script works but I wanted to know where I am making mistake.

Comment: Yeah, me too! I know it's not a good answer, just wanted to provide a possible workaround.